# jQuery Ajax метод проверки php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Допустим я отправляю ajax post с "уникальным значением" в php, как обезопасить такой post в php, если заранее значение будет неизвестно, но обычная ajax post подставка через ту же консоль не прошла, то есть разрешить, только те значения, которые будут даны скриптом.

P.s. Значение может любое числовое. Суть в том, что бы php точно понимал, что эти значения сгенерированы скриптом, а не прописаны в другом источнике, как например консоль разработчика.

пример запроса.

```
result = randomint();
$.ajax({
            method: "POST", 
            url: "test.php", 
            data: "test+value="+result,                
            success: function(data) { 
                console.log('success');
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {console.log("ERROR:" + xhr.responseText+" - "+thrownError);}
        });
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: если под "сгенерированы скриптом", имеется в виду яваскриптом, то, разумеется, никак не проверить

Comment: И если всё так секретно, то непонятно, зачем вообще генерировать в жс,а не в РНР

Comment: Зачем вообще передавать секретные генерируемые данные на стороне клиента? Почему не делать на серверной стороне?

Answer (score 0):

Что тебе мешает генерировать рандомный ключ, помещать в сессию. Шифровать его. Передавать этот зашифрованный ключ через ajax. Потом, в нужном месте дешифровать, сравнивать значения.